# Simple Code Explanation in Java Beginner Test

Tags: java

When running the following program:

```
int i = 0;
boolean t = true;
boolean f = false, b;
b = (t || ((i++) == 0));
b = (f || ((i+=2) > 0));
System.out.println(i);
```

the answer is 2. Why?

Comment: What exactly is bothering you? You don't understand what happens?

Comment: What do *you* think the answer should be, and how did you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: `i++` is not being evaluated because `t` is `true`. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an OR statement in Java the left side is evaluated first and if it appears to be true the right side of the statement is considered not important, so Java doesn't check that side.

So in your case the i++ in de right side of the statement is not being called because t is true.

Answer (score 2):

What's hapenning is due to the fact that the [conditional-or operator `||`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24) is short-circuiting (emphasis mine):

> The conditional-or operator `||` operator is like `|` (§15.22.2), **but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is `false`**.

```
b = (t || ((i++) == 0));
```

In this line, `t` is `true` so the right-hand operand is not evaluated and the result is `true`. After this step, `i` is still 0.

```
b = (f || ((i+=2) > 0));
```

In this case, however, `f` is `false` so the right-hand operand *is* evaluated. This operand, among other things, evaluates `i+=2` so `i`, which was 0 becomes 2 at the end of the evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it step by step.

```
b = (t || ((i++) == 0));
```

t evaluates to true and you have operator ||, which means that the JVM won't execute the second part - true || false == true and true || true == true, which means that the second part doesn't matter

```
b = (f || ((i+=2) > 0));
```

Now f evaluates to false. This time the VM doesn't know the answer of the expression, since it depends on the second one, so it evaluates (i+=2) > 0; Hence i becomes 2

Answer (score 0):

Very simple

```
 1. int i = 0;
 2. boolean t = true;
 3. boolean f = false, b;
 4. b = (t || ((i++) == 0));
 5. b = (f || ((i+=2) > 0));
 6. System.out.println(i);
```

Line 1. i is 0

line 2. t is true

line 3. f is false, b is boolean

line 4. since t is true so `||` doesn't evaluate the part of `(i++==0)` even if it is false

line 5. f is false so here `(i+=2)>0` is evaluated bcoz `||` evaluates util it get at least one true

line 6. i is 2 due to line 5

Note: if | is used in place of || so all parts are evaluated
|| matches the first true to return true for all
| matches all parts but needs at least one true